# How to get Height of an "element in 'auto 'mode" when it's height actually is not 'auto'? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to get height of an element when it the height is auto, but I don't want to turn the actual height to 'auto', to find it. Let's say, now the heigh = '100vh'. I don't want to change it to 'auto', but I need to get height in pixels like it would be auto.

Basicly it is a div with a text. I use the following code, but it doesn't work without delay: `setTimeout(() => {...}, 1);`

```
<style>
#one {
height:100vh;
width:30vw;
background-color:rgb(1,1,1);
display:block;
float:left;}
</style>

<div id="one">
  <p> A lot of text here </p>
</div>

<script>
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
   var one = document.getElementById("one");


   one.style.height = 'auto';

   if (window.innerHeight > one.clientHeight )
   {
      one.style.height = '100vh';
   }
   else
   {
      one.style.height = 'auto';
   }
}, true);
</script>
```

**The problem is that it doesn't have enought time to convert the height to auto and then to excecute the if else statement. So, if I wrap it in `setTimeout(() => {...}, 1);` delay it starts to work correctly.
But without the delay it doesn't work.**

So, if I wrap it it looks like this:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
       var one = document.getElementById("one");

    
       one.style.height = 'auto';
  
       setTimeout(() => {
          if (window.innerHeight > one.clientHeight )
          {
             one.style.height = '100vh';
          }
          else
          {
             one.style.height = 'auto';
          }
       }, 0.1);
    }, true);
</script>
```

But in this way while you resize the window it starts to excecute the first condition, and then the second, and then back the first, only because it doen't have time to turn it the height before the if else statement to 'auto'.

**So I either need to make it faster to make it workable without the delay(what is not possible for some reason) or to get rid of the temporary changing of the height to auto.**

So, basicly I have a little bit more complicated code, but it will take a lot of your time to explore it deeply. So I made it shorter and more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the height to auto, measure it, and then delete the inline css (or revert it), and as long as you *don't* have a timeout or anything in between, it will all happen before a repaint can occur anyways - the client will never see it because it never actually happened:

```js
document.getElementById('demo').style.height='auto';
const height = document.getElementById('demo').clientHeight;
document.getElementById('demo').style.height='';
console.log(`${height}px`)
```

```css
#demo {
    height: 100vh;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">Hi</div>
```

To prove that it never happens, we have a timeout (just to let initial render complete), then we set the height to auto, busy loop for 10 seconds, then change it back - you'll never see the height change:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById('demo').style.height='auto';
  const height = document.getElementById('demo').clientHeight;
  const now = Date.now();
  while (Date.now() - now < 10000) {}
  document.getElementById('demo').style.height='';
  console.log(`${height}px`)
}, 100);
```

```css
#demo {
    height: 100vh;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">Hi</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @dave for the answer. I've just edited the question. Now it is clearer. Please reread it if you have time. So, mainly the problem is that the script doesn't have time to turn the height to auto, and it excecutes it without it. But, if I include a delay, it starts to work perfectly. I don't need the delay, because it is noticible, so, I want to change the lines one.style.height = 'auto' and one.clientHeight to something shorter.